# Google Sheets: Obtain hyperlink from =ImportXML while importing title

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to have the title of the website, along with having it hyperlinked to said website in the same cell.

I've tried doing:

```
ImportXML("https://wwww.example.com/","//title/text()","//a/@href()")
```

Comment: You could try using the `HYPERLINK` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following formula:
    =hyperlink("https://www.example.com/",ImportXML("https://www.example.com/","//title/text()"))